# Adjective that describes giving life or soul to some thing

Tags: adjectives

looking for an adjective that describes putting life/soul to something.

If i were to coin a word i would say Soulify... though it doesn't sound great.

Context:
Tag line for a system, that would energize, put life, put soul to an item.

Thanks.

Comment: The word should describe a transcendental force that puts a thing to life. Approximation of what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions (from [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vivifying), plus one of my own):

> - animating
> - enlivening
> - quickening,
> - rousing
> - stimulating
> - vitalizing
> - vivifying